# Replace text between brackets in Java

Tags: java, string, replace, between, brackets

I'm trying to code a program for personal purposes, it works but with some ... yeah.

I want my output to be like this:

```
Hello yourname!
```

but the current output is like this:

```
Hello {yourname}!
```

Here's the pattern I'm using:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}").matcher(text);
```

Every help will get me close.

PS:
I've already tried to replace the brackets with the `replaceAll(char, char)` method, but it throws a pattern exception!

Answer (score 3):

```java
public static String replaceText(String str, String value) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\{[^}]+\\}", value);
}
```

**Demo:**

```java
System.out.println(replaceText("Hello {yourname}!", "Oleg"));
// Hello Oleg!
```